# How to deal with too much data coming from webservice? OOM

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I'm developing a app that is going to be used in field without Internet connection. The user has to import the data that is going to be used by city before going to the field. At the first time the app brings all the data from the city. Here is the problem, how should I deal with that? Some cities has too much data, some times more than 4000 producers, and each producers has more than 40 fields at the table.

Here is my handler class:

```
package emater.gin.webservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/*
 * Classe: ServiceHandler
 * Usada para leitura e envio de JSON.
 */
public class ServiceHandler 
{

    //Resposta
    private String response = null;

    //Recebe do servidor.
    public final static int GET = 1;

    //Envia para o servidor.
    public final static int POST = 2;

    //Construtor vazio.
    public ServiceHandler() {}

    //Faz a chamada para o servidor.
    public String makeServiceCall( String url, int method )
    {

        return this.makeServiceCall( url, method, null );

    }

    //Faz a chamada para o servidor.
    public String makeServiceCall( String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params )
    {

        try
        {

            //HTTP Client.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Entidade que pode ser enviada ou recebida.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            //Resposta HTTP.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            //Checa o tipo de request que vai ser feito.
            if( method == POST )
            {

                //Cria o HttpPost para enviar uma entidade.
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( url );

                //Adicona os parametros ao post.
                if( params != null )
                {

                    //Seta a entidade de respostas no httppost com os parametros passados.
                    httpPost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params ) );

                }

                //Pega a resposta do servidor a partida da enviada.
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPost );

            }else if( method == GET )
            {

                //Adiciona os parametros e gera a URL.
                if( params != null )
                {

                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format( params, "utf-8" );

                    url += "?" + paramString;

                }

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( url );

                //Envia a URL e pega a resposta.
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpGet );

            }

            //Liberar memoria.
            httpClient = null;

            //Pega a resposta e bota em uma nova entidade para ser usada.
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            //Liberar memoria.
            httpResponse = null;

            response = EntityUtils.toString( httpEntity );

            //Liberar memoria.
            httpEntity = null;

        }catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch( ClientProtocolException e ) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch( IOException e )
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

I get the OOM at the line of the response, when I get all the string from the webservice.
And here is the code where I call the server:

```
// Instancia para adicionar os parâmetros.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// Adiciona os parametros a serem passados para o webservice.
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
            MunicipioUsuarioController.COLUMN_MUNICIPIO_ID, municipioId));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numeroserie", Secure.getString(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID)));

// Instancia quem vai lidar com o webservice.
ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();

// Faz um request a URL e pega a resposta.
String JSONString = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(
            HTTP_URL_DADOS_MUNICIPIO, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
```

I use a AsyncTask to do the call. I used MAT and that JSONString was occupying most of the memory that my app had. How should I deal with that problem? Import only some amount of data at a time?

Comment: What is the "problem?" Does it crash? Is it slow?

Comment: Make your service deliver not so much data. Try to have different calls for more specific data, or cutting it down before sending it back to the client...

Comment: Yes it sounds like you are trying to do too much at once, only download what you really need, preload what might be needed, and do the rest on demand.

Comment: @323go, The problem is the big string, its occupying most of the memory, and sometimes I get OOM.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings I'll try something like that, but that is the only solution?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Well, the first time it's has to download everything, after that only what was updated.

Comment: Why does it have to download everything? If there is so much data that you are really running into `OutOfMemoryExceptions` than there is no question that it is **WAY WAY TOO MUCH**. As I previously said the best practice is to: Only download what you really need, preload what might be needed, and do the rest on demand.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The user'll use the app offline most of the time, because there is no Internet connection where he is going. I'll try another approach.

Comment: You have to remember that 200 kB is the absolute maximum for a payload of a webservice, above that and the load times will literally be a drag on everything. The smaller the payload the faster and more fluent will be your app which will result in a much better user experience.

Comment: Is it static data? You could just package it with your app, or at least as much as possible.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The data is not static, that data comes from a web system, and it can be updated,created and etc. The static data I bring with the app already at the first start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you an take to address this.

First off, as suggested in comments, try to have your server return less data. It seems like an obvious solution, but it will require work on both ends of your connection.

Secondly, parse the data from stream:

What you're currently doing is to turn the response into a `String`, then pass back that `String` and then parse it into JSON. A better approach here is to handle the JSON parsing from the http entity, as below (only showing relevant code).

```
public Object makeServiceCall( String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params ) {
    ....    
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        httpResponse = null;

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
        response = parser.parse( httpEntity.getContent() );
```

Obviously, you'd need to catch parse exceptions and such, but that's the gist of it. I've done this with an HttpUrlConnection, and was able to handle several mega bytes of responses for static loads.

The main issue, as far as I was able to determine, wasn't the overall memory usage, but rather the size of the largest chunk of memory needed to accommodate the response. When parsing the `InputStream` directly, this isn't an issue as it creates many smaller objects which don't need contiguous heap.

Comment: I couldn't understand much of what you said, but I'll try to learn more about InputStrem. I'm only a trainee, there is no one who knows about android development where I work, they gave me this hard task, but I'm enjoying every minute.

Comment: Good luck with Android, and welcome aboard! What I'm saying is that, in your code, currently, you're grabbing the http response as a string, which means you need a chunk of memory to hold the entire response. I assume you then later parse that response into JSON, and then store it in a database. My suggestion is to skip the step where you have the entire response loaded, and rather parse the response into JSON as it arrives. When you're done, you still have the entire response available as a JSON object tree.

Comment: Now I understood, thanks for the explanation, I'll not use the string anymore, thanks!